# Common interface for several modules

Tags: haskell

I want to give a user an ability to run the program with `import DryRun` first and then with `import Do` if he thinks everything is correct.
So there is a module which does actual work:

```
doThis ∷ SomeStack ()
doThis = actuallyDoThis
...
doThat ∷ SomeStack ()
doThat = actuallyDoThat
```

and a module for shy user:

```
doThis ∷ SomeStack ()
doThis = liftIO $ putStrLn "DoThis"
...
doThat ∷ SomeStack ()
doThat = liftIO $ puStrlLn "DoThat"
```

The problem is I cannot be sure that interfaces in `Do` and `DryRun` are the same (compiler cannot help) and this mess is hard to maintain during development.
Are there any common idioms to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Is making the two implementations instances of the same typeclass an option?

Comment: @GregBacon Well, two copies of monad stacks are certainly an option but if there is something not involving copying I'd use that.

Comment: Run haddock on both modules and compare the resulting documents?

Comment: Does `SomeStack` also vary depending on whether your `Do` or `DryRun` module is included, or is this the same type in both?

Answer (score 2):

You could reify the modules in question. That is, in a base module define a datatype:

```
module Base where
data MyModule = MyModule {
    doThis_ :: SomeStack (),
    doThat_ :: SomeStack ()
}
```

with the stuff you need each module to export (The reason for the underscores will become apparent soon).

Then you could in each of the modules define values of this type, e.g.:

```
module DryRun(moduleImpl) where
import Base
moduleImpl :: MyModule
moduleImpl = MyModule doThis doThat
-- doThis and doThat defined as above, with liftIO . putStrLn

module Do(moduleImpl) where
import Base
moduleImpl :: MyModule
moduleImpl = MyModule doThis doThat
-- doThis and doThat defined as above, where the real work gets done
```

I don't construct the `MyModule` values using record syntax to make sure that if `MyModule` changes, the type checker will start complaining in most cases.

In the client module you could do

```
module Client where
import DryRun
-- import Do -- uncomment as needed

doThis = doThis_ moduleImpl
doThat = doThat_ moduleImpl

-- do whatever you want here
```

Now you know that the same operations are exported by both modules. This is tedious and clunky, for sure, but since Haskell doesn't have first-class modules, you'll always have to work around the limitations of the module system. The good thing is that you only have to write the Base and Client modules once, and that you can start defining combinators operating on `MyModule` values. E.g.

```
doNothing = MyModule (return ()) (return ())
addTracing impl = MyModule ((liftIO $ putStrLn "DoThis") >> doThis_ impl) 
                           ((liftIO $ putStrLn "DoThat") >> doThat_ impl)
```

will allow you to replace the `DryRun` module implementation by `addTracing doNothing` if I'm not mistaken.